# Glide is not showing Firestore images in Recycle View in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview

I am new in this field. I am trying to show images and text in Recycle View. Text appears after running but images not loading. I changed my code again and again but still not working. I am not sure where I did wrong. I have uploaded images into Firebase Storage and then copy the access token URL. I made documents with categoryName and icon field in Collection named Categories. I need your help please help me to solve this problem

**HomeFragment.kt**

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var recycler:RecyclerView
    private lateinit var Firestore:FirebaseFirestore

    companion object {
        fun newInstance() = HomeFragment()
    }

    private lateinit var viewModel: HomeViewModel

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_fragment, container, false)

        recycler=view.findViewById(R.id.recycler)
        recycler.layoutManager=LinearLayoutManager(context,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
        recycler.setHasFixedSize(true)

        Firestore= FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        Firestore.collection("Categories").get()
            .addOnCompleteListener { p0 ->
                var categoriesList: MutableList<CategoryModel> = mutableListOf()
                if (p0.isSuccessful) {
                    for (data in p0.result!!) {
                        categoriesList.add(
                            CategoryModel(
                                data.get("categoryName") as String,
                                data.get("icon") as String
                            )
                        )
                    }
                    var catAdapter: CategoryAdapter = CategoryAdapter(categoriesList)
                    recycler.adapter = catAdapter
                    catAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

                }
            }
        return view
    }
    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(HomeViewModel::class.java)
       
    }

}
```

**CategoryAdapter.kt**

```
class CategoryAdapter(val categoryList:List<CategoryModel>):RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoryAdapter
.CategoryHolder>() 
{
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup,viewType: Int
    ): CategoryAdapter.CategoryHolder {
       val inflator=LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.single_category_row,parent,false)
        return CategoryHolder(inflator)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CategoryAdapter.CategoryHolder, position: Int) {
        if(categoryList[position].icon!=null){
            holder.bind(categoryList[position])
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
     return categoryList.size
    }
    inner class CategoryHolder(itemView: View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
        val catName:TextView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView8)
        val image:ImageView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_category_title)

        fun bind(category:CategoryModel){
            catName.text=category.categoryName
            Glide.with(itemView.context).load(category.icon).into(image)
        }

    }
}
```

**single_category_row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    >

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_category_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView8"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_sans_bold"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/image_category_title"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/image_category_title"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/image_category_title"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

**CategoryModel.kt**

```
package com.example.mineralsroute.ui.utils

data class CategoryModel(var categoryName:String?=null, var icon:String?=null)

**home_fragment.xml**
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".ui.home.HomeFragment">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNav"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:listitem="@layout/single_category_row"
            />

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottomNav"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="58dp"
            app:elevation="2dp"
            app:itemBackground="@color/brown"
            app:itemIconSize="24dp"
            app:itemIconTint="@color/bottom_nav_item"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/bottom_nav_item"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/recycler"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_menu" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Does the value `categoryName` shows up?

Comment: Yes only categoryName Value is Showing

Comment: Did you test the icon String? What I mean is, copy the string and paste to browser. Does it show the image?

Comment: Yes I have tested all access token links they are working in browser

Comment: What does "category.icon" return?